# http requests with dart

Tags: dart, httprequest

I am trying to learn dart, experimenting with http requests from [this blog](https://codeburst.io/quick-tip-how-to-make-http-requests-in-dart-53fc407daf31).

So I installed dart on Windows but for whatever reason I cant seem to run this script:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';



void main() {
  var data = { 'title' : 'My first post' };
  HttpRequest.request(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    method: 'POST',
    sendData: json.encode(data),
    requestHeaders: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
  )
  .then((resp) {
    print(resp.responseUrl);
    print(resp.responseText);           
  });
}


// Response
// https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
// { "title": "My first post", "id": "101" }
```

When I run this from Windows terminal `$dart run script.dart` this will error:

```
script.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
script.dart:8:3: Error: Undefined name 'HttpRequest'.
  HttpRequest.request(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But in the blog post there is a link to [dart pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?) where the code runs just fine. Any ideas to try? Thanks for any incite

```
$dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable) (Tue Dec 14 13:32:21 2021 +0100) on "windows_x64"
```

Comment: importing from `dart:html` is only available when compiling dart to javascript. There is another implementation of `HttpRequest` in `dart:io`, so if you are targeting a platform other than javascript, you can import `dart:io` here instead.

Comment: Also, if you want to make http requests in a way that will work on all platforms, then you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/http .

Comment: Would there be a any chance you could post an answer? Doesn't matter the site URL, just curious to experiment with a POST or GET with dart and json responses. The link you sent has some examples in it but I cant get any of those to work either when just using dart natively not in javascript or flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package, is the preferred approach since it will work consistently on all platforms.

The same request can be made by doing the following:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  var data = {'title': 'My first post'};
  http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
    body: json.encode(data),
  ).then((resp) {
    print(resp.body);
  });
}
```

Although typically `async`/`await` syntax is used instead:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var data = {'title': 'My first post'};
  var resp = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
    body: json.encode(data),
  );
  print(resp.body);
}
```

Comment: Could there be an issue that I dont have a package installed? `Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'.`

Comment: Yes, you will need to add the `http` package as a dependency. If you go to the page on the pub website there is a tab called "installing" that will explain how to add it as a dependency.

Comment: I am just experimenting around with learning how to code in dart. When I run `dart pub add http` I get an error that there is no `pubspec.yaml`. Do I need a  `pubspec.yaml` file in my directory I am experimenting with dart? I think like a flutter app? I was hoping it would be like pip with python or npm with javascript?

Comment: Actually there is info here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/libraries/shared-pkgs

Comment: All of your dependencies will be listed in the `pubspec.yaml` file. If you create a dart project from the command line using `dart create` it will create a `pubspec.yaml` file for you among other things. But you can add one manually as well, you will need to add a few properties in manually though, I think at bare minimum you need `name` and `environment`.